# Solution to Repetative Task using only Python

Tags: python-3.x, automation

We do a repatative task of passing an ID to a system, after few seconds the ID will be generatd into a new ID, is there a automated solution in python wherein we give the ID to python programme and it returns the new ID after generating? without our intervention with the system using only python?

Comment: Questions that are asking "where do I start", "is it possible" or for pointers are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. Please do some [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) then if this leads to specific issues you can address your post.

Comment: Sure, Thank You :)